# Creating directional animation using canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am utilizing [FabricJs](http://fabricjs.com/) it is a javascript canvas library to make a small application where you can create shapes and animation between different objects.

To Run it You can follow the following steps.

- 1. Click new animation
- 2. Click Rectangle
- 3. Click Add Child button (This allows you to link objects)
- 4. Click Circle or Rectangle

If you follow the steps above you will see that you can create 2 shapes and animation between the two displayed by a small circle going back and forth.

I was wondering if it is possible to create similar animation that goes either left to right or right to left only once. I would really appreciate if someone can guide me.

Here is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s6ju2858/)

Here is the code for the animation

```
var animateBallBetweenObjects = function (obj1, obj2) {

    // Add the "ball"

    var circle = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 10,
        fill: 'blue',
        left: obj1.getCenterPoint().x,
        top: obj1.getCenterPoint().y,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'middle',
        selectable: false
    });

    canvas.add(circle);

    var period = 1000;
    var amplitude = 0;
    var angle = 0;
    var prevTime = Date.now();

    var loop = function () {

        // Calculate the new amplitude

        var now = Date.now();
        var elapsed = now - prevTime;
        prevTime = now;
        angle += Math.PI * (elapsed / (period * 0.5));
        amplitude = 0.5 * (Math.sin(angle - (0.5 * Math.PI)) + 1);

        // Set the new position

        var obj1Center = obj1.getCenterPoint();
        var obj2Center = obj2.getCenterPoint();

        circle.setLeft(obj1Center.x + (amplitude * (obj2Center.x - obj1Center.x)));
        circle.setTop(obj1Center.y + (amplitude * (obj2Center.y - obj1Center.y)));
        canvas.renderAll();

        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }

    // Animate as fast as possible

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};
```

Comment: Please post you code.

Comment: @Oleander I have just posted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try yo use fabric built in animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/asturur/s6ju2858/2/

I did not replicate your loop function, that requires extra work, but fabricJS  gives you the ability to define an animation for a property ( in our case left and top ) with a start and end value.

```
var animateBallBetweenObjects = function (obj1, obj2) {
    var completedLeft, completedTop;
    // obj1, obj2 are predefined.
    var c1 = obj1.getCenterPoint();
    var c2 = obj2.getCenterPoint();
    var circle = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 10,
        fill: 'blue',
        left: c1.x,
        top: c1.y,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        selectable: false
    });

    canvas.add(circle);

    circle.animate('left', c2.x, {
      onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
      startValue: c1.x,
      endValue: c2.x,
      onComplete: function() {
        completedLeft = true;
        completedTop && canvas.remove(circle);
      },
      easing: fabric.util.ease['easeInQuad']
    }).animate('top', c2.y, {
      startValue: c1.y,
      endValue: c2.y,
      onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
      onComplete: function() {
        completedTop = true;
        completedLeft && canvas.remove(circle);
      },
      easing: fabric.util.ease['easeInQuad']
    });
};
```

Updated fiddle with ball removal at the end of animation.

Comment: This is quite an interesting approach also. I was wondering is there anyway to get rid of the animation ball after it animates.

Comment: of course, as you see there is an onComplete callback.

Comment: Hi i posted another question it is a build up on this question I think you would probably be in the best position to help me please check it if you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006293/storing-fabric-js-animation